# Any way to speed up RSS loading on an android app

Tags: android, performance, xamarin.forms, rss, rss-reader

I have to load around 25 rss feeds for the home page and that usually takes around 30s, which makes the app very slow. I was loading this in a nested for loop 5x5

After that, i tried loading them with parallelism with 5 tasks at a time and once they are done put them in a list. This produced slightly faster results but not much.

I thought of loading all 25 rss feeds at the same time at parallel , but this would eat up a lot of memory and crash the app.

Any suggestions on how to make rss loading faster. It just loads the title and one image.

Comment: *"which makes the app very slow"* is quite an inexact problem description. Are we talking loading time, or the time it takes to show contents in your app? I'm asking, because they differ significantly in their root cause and prospective solutions.

Comment: It takes a lot of time loading the rss. The showing of the content does not appear to be the problem

Comment: Alright, you said *"it only loads the title and one image"*, any chance of caching this data?

Comment: Found the issue, some websites that I'm loading from are really slow. I just filtered them out and everything works a lot faster.

Comment: If you remove the slow website, this issue is disappear, please move your comment to answer and accept it after three days, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, some websites that I'm loading from are really slow. I just filtered them out and everything works a lot faster.